# How to get the path part of a filename?

Tags: matlab, path, filenames

I want to get the path part of a file name in MATLAB like [`dirname`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname) and [`basename`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) in Linux. I've tried to turn to find a function like [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strrchr), but I failed. I know `strtok`, `strfind` and `textscan` can be used, but I want to accomplish this with not more than two statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this particular problem I suggest you use the [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function:

```
[path, filename, extension] = fileparts(str)
```

Comment: another useful matlab command in this context is [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) that allows for concatenating folder names to paths in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 3):

Nick's answer definitely does what you ask for, but here's an alternative answer using [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
regexprep(str, '(.+)(?:\\|/)(.*)', '$1')
```

If you'd want to capture the filename (extension included), use the `$2` token instead of `$1`.
It's a good exercise for regular expressions, which prove to be *very* useful in MATLAB when parsing text.

Comment: what about paths on Linux?

Comment: fileparts takes that into account

Comment: Why should anyone prefer this approach to the one that @Nick has proposed ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No reason in particular. It might prove to be useful for other users who are looking for a way of "tokenizing" path strings in a more advanced way, and stumble upon this question.

Comment: why not using [`filesep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html)?

Comment: @Shai It's possible, but IMO it'll just mess up the pattern string. I'm getting the same functionality as `fileparts` simply by treating backslashes as slashes.

Comment: I think EitanT's answer is more general than Nick's. Thank you.

Comment: @CookSchelling thanks, but you should be accepting Nick's answer, his is better suited for your priblem, while mine is just a general suggestion for tokenizing strings.

Comment: @CookSchelling, honestly I think my answer fits your problem better. As EitanT says, his solution is better for parsing strings.

Comment: it's great since it works for a cell of strings as well!