# Matlab - remove part of string

Tags: string, matlab, replace

I have a list of strings that look like this:

`/disk1/home/alb/main/directory1/image0001.png`

I want to remove everything after the last / and end up with a string that looks like this:

`/disk1/home/alb/main/directory1/`

Is there a fast way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the path part of a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476200/how-to-get-the-path-part-of-a-filename)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the [first output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html#bsl_mpz) of [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html?refresh=true) as it is guaranteed to work on all platforms. The `fileparts` function is a built-in designed to separate a path into it's directory, filename, and file extension.

```
string = '/disk1/home/alb/main/directory1/image0001.png'
part = fileparts(string);
```

If you really need that trailing slash (you shouldn't if you use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to (correctly) construct a new path), then you can add it to the end using `filesep`.

```
part_with_slash = [part, filesep];
```

If for some reason you are trying to process this *nix file path on a Windows machine (which has a different file separator), **Only** then you could use the following `regexp`.

```
part = regexp(string, '.*/', 'match');
```

Comment: Forgot about this function while answering, removed my answer since this is definitely the best solution. +1 for platform independence

Comment: Fun fact: `fileparts` just uses `find` to locate locations of `/`, ``\``, and the last `.`

Comment: @excaza And does all of the nice checking to ensure compatibility with UNC paths and cases where you only pass it a filename with no leading directory :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
str = "/path/to/file.png"

regexprep(str,'([A-Za-z0-9]\.png)?','once')
```

The ? makes it lazy, this is, the shortest match possible.

Comment: thank you, this works really well in the example i gave. My name of directories is a little more complicated, i gave a simpler version to make things simpler. My string looks like this : '/disk1/home/alb/main/directory1/direct1_subdir1_image0001.png' When i use your solution it removes the png but not the whole direct1_subdir1_imag0001. Any ideas how to solve this?